# python - Difference of typing with AsyncGenerator or AsyncIterator?

Tags: python, asynchronous, iterator, generator, python-typing

I make creating a discord asynchronous library that is fully typed.
I have a method that create objects from a aiohttp get requests such as the following example:

```py
async def get_bans(self):
    """|coro|
    Fetches all the bans in the guild.
    """
    data = await self._http.get(f"guilds/{self.id}/bans")
    for ban_data in data:
        yield Ban.from_dict(construct_client_dict(self._client, ban_data))
```

I was wondering about the return type of this code snippet and whether it should be a `AsyncGenerator[Ban, None]` or `AsyncIterator[Ban, None]`. To be honest i have been searching for a bit, and i could find any information that would gave me a clear idea on the subject.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Official documentation describes [AsyncIterator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.AsyncIterator)  as:

> ... that provide `__aiter__` and `__anext__` methods ...

[AsyncGenerator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.AsyncGenerator) leads from documentation to [PEP525](https://peps.python.org/pep-0525/#asynchronous-generators).

> ... generator is any function containing one or more `yield` expressions ...

> The result of calling an asynchronous generator function is an asynchronous generator object ...

> Asynchronous generators define both of these methods (`__aiter__` and `__anext__`)

So I think, because of `yield` in your function it's better to use `AsyncGenerator`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm looking at it from a semantics point of view.

The `AsyncGenerator` is the inheritor of `AsyncIterator`. From Python 3.12 sources:

```
class AsyncGenerator(AsyncIterator[_YieldT_co], Generic[_YieldT_co, _SendT_contra]): ...
```

The brief checks to confirm this:

```
>>> async def gen_or_iter():
...   yield 1
... 
>>> x = gen_or_iter()
>>> isinstance(x, typing.AsyncGenerator)
True
>>> isinstance(x, typing.AsyncIterator)
True
>>>
```

In my opinion, if using `asend()` is not applicable for concrete generator implementation, in other words, the function doesn't use expressions like `x = yield` and behaves as a pure iterator the `AsyncGenerator[T, None]` is semantically identical to `AsyncIterator[T]`.

So despite the `AsyncGenerator[T, None]` being a more precise declaration, in the cases of pure iterator behavior using the `AsyncIterator[T]` might be correct and reasonable too.